# Check if date format contains year or month?

Tags: python, datetime

I can have a date string such as :

```
4.3.2009 (my output is 'day' because user meant a day)
3.2009 (my output is 'month' because user meant March)
4/3/2009 (same - output is day)
4-2009 ( output is month)
```

I am using `dateutil` to parse the string but can't check format.
I just need to know the *type*, doesn't matter if it's `'month'`, `'M'`, or other output.
I know I can ask the format with  `datetime.strftime(string,format)` but this won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For diversity matching, you can use regular expressions[`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re).

`(\d{1,2}\D+?)?(\d{1,2}\D+?\d{4})`

> When the match is successful and there is a value in group 1, it means `day`, and when the match is successful and group 1 has no value, it means `month`.

```py
import re

dates_str = ['4.3.2009', '3.2009', '4/3/2009', '4-2009']

regex = re.compile(r"(\d{1,2}\D+?)?(\d{1,2}\D+?\d{4})")


def func(v):
    res = regex.match(v)
    if res:
        if all(res.groups()):
            return "day"
        else:
            return "month"
    return ""


for date_str in dates_str:
    print(func(date_str))
```

Output:

```
day
month
day
month
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by splitting the date strings like this:

```
dates = ['4.3.2009', '3.2009', '4/3/2009', '4-2009']

def check(date):
    for c in date:
        if not c.isdigit():
            t = date.split(c)
            if len(t) == 2:
                return 'month'
            if len(t) == 3:
                return 'day'
            break
    return None

for date in dates:
    print(check(date))
```

**Output:**

```
day
month
day
month
```

**Note:**

check() function will return None if the input string does not contain something that looks like a date. It does not validate the given string. For example, '99-99-99' would return 'day'. You could extend the function to build a strptime format string based on the identified separator